# Eclipse: "Failed to connect to any server" when trying to create Factory over Wildfly

Tags: java, eclipse, server, wildfly, factory-pattern

I've added a connection factory at the `standalone-full` file of Wildfly:

```xml
<jms-connection-factories>
    <connection-factory name="K19Factory">
        <connectors>
            <connector-ref connector-name="netty"/>
        </connectors>
        <entries>
            <entry name="K19Factory"/>
            <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/K19Factory"/>
        </entries>
    </connection-factory>
    ...
</jms-connection-factories>
```

And so  a code on Eclipse to use it. But I'm having problems at the moment of the creation of the factory:

```
 ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory)ic.lookup("jms/K19Factory");
```

When trying to run this line, I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to any server. Servers tried: [remote://localhost:4447 (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information)]
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.failOverSequence(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:244)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.namingStore(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:149)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.namingOperation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:130)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.lookup(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:272)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:87)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:129)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.k19.emissores.EnviaNovoPedidoJBoss.main(EnviaNovoPedidoJBoss.java:30)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I think it listens on port 8080 with the `http-remoting` protocol.

Comment: I treid to add  this :      

props.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "http-remoting://192.168.3.93:8080");

But it returns a  " Operation failed with status WAITING after 5000 MILLISECONDS "

Answer (score 0):

```
Properties prop=new Properties();
        prop.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        prop.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://localhost:8080");
        prop.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);  
        Context ctx = new InitialContext(prop);
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the exact error log when trying to connect JBoss from my code. Issue was fixed once I removed all other jars in build path with jboss-client.jar.